# How does fusing weapons affect durability?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

How does fusing weapons and items together affect durability? For example, if I fuse a boulder to a sword, will that change how times I can attack with the sword before it breaks? What if I fuse a sword that's never been used with a sword that is badly damaged?

Answer (score 10):

Simply put, fusing can grant up to a +25 durability buffer. As long as this buffer exists the weapon itself won't be damaged and hits will drain the buffer instead.

Not every fusion material will give a full 25 durability buffer. Some "low quality" items seem to give less. In that case should you defuse the weapon and attach a different item you can still gain **the residual bonus**.
Once you consumed the full 25 points, fusing won't have any further effect on durability.

Source: [empirical experimentation by a reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOTK/comments/13bnlx0/testing_how_durabilty_and_fuse_interact_detailed/)

Note: it is still unknown if "repairing" the weapon has any effect on the buffer itself...

---

**ADD-ON: A clarification on the buffer mechanic, as asked by Stevoisiak.**

The durability buffer you can get from fusing is stacked on top of the weapon durability and is not considered part of it by the game. While this does not affect the "number of uses" that you can get from the weapon it means that the weapon "color" indicator of its durability is NOT affected by the buffer.

To put it simply:

- you have a never fused before weapon that is "about to break" (should be 3 durability left) and thus displayed in red
- you fuse a diamond and gain a full +25 durability buffer
- the weapon original durability won't go down until you consume said buffer but the weapon will still be displayed as red and "about to break".

Sadly this means that you can't really know how much "durability buffer" you have left on a weapon. Therefore if you really want to save a weapon that is about to break, fusing may not be your best option.
Try something else...

... I once heard that the old methods our parents used to clean up rust from weapons work even better now...

Comment: What do you mean by durability buffer? Does it mean only 25 durability will get used up on the weapon being fused to, then any other hits won't drain it?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I mean that the "buffer" is consumed before consuming the regular item durability but it is not seen as part of it.  If you have a weapon that is already "about to break" and fuse an item on it and get the durability bonus the weapon icon **will stay red** but the weapon won't get further damage until the buffer is consumed.

Comment: So, if I get it right: That buffer is basically a second ressource that prevents the weapon from being damaged until it is itself exhausted. So fusing a weapon right away is useful, because even if you fuse later, its gonna 'heal' the same amount. Basically, fusing right away makes the HP go from 100/100 to 125/100, and fusing later will just make the total hp go from 20/100 to 55/100

Comment: @Fredy31 With the caveat that the buffer is per weapon, not per fused material. Going from 125/100 down to 20/100 and then re-fusing will not increase you to 55/100, but leave you at 20/100 with the new fused item -- you can only benefit from the bonus durability once (though it can be over multiple materials if the fused item is replaced before those extra 25 hits)

Comment: I didnt even know you could refuse. I thought I tried and was told 'This item is already fused with something'

Comment: @RavenDreamer correct.

Comment: @Fredy31 you obviously have to de-fuse before trying a new fusion. See the other question about that.

Comment: @Fredy31 You tried to attach a new item to your weapon, but the game *refused* to let you do so.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the other answer, the majority of the items you can fuse add exactly **25 durability points** at the time of fusing. This includes material, monster parts and other items.
The new durability bonus gets used up before the base weapon durability, whatever it is.

To add something to [Ꮢedacted's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/402808/87579):

A similar logic applies when fusing a weapon to another weapon, but instead of getting +25 bonus you add the attached weapon durabilty, which simply breaks when it's used up.
This means that if you attach two weapons only the attached one will get its durability reduced, and when it breaks you'll remain with the base weapon (with the same durability it has before the fuse).

However, you can't exploit this bonus forever, since **only 25 extra durability points** are allowed per weapon.
For example, a wooden stick has 12 durability points, if you fuse it with another one you'll get a weapon with 24 durability points. After the attached stick breaks, if you fuse a boulder on it you don't get the expected 25 durability points, but only 13 points (25 - 12 already used).

Not every weapon has a potential durability bonus of 25, for example:

- rusty weapons, royal guard weapons, tree branches and torches only have 10
- Gerudo weapons only have 5
- bone weapons only have 3

Think about it before fusing anything valuable on this weapons!

Source, [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FOe4spSahY).
Also, take a look at [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18pNtDx3z-8CwGJRmlW574xbQ6VphQOkvpZhClpOEVDA/edit#gid=114269320) for further stats.