# What is the best strategy for weapons fusing? Fuse something into it right away or wait until it's almost broken?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I know when you fuse something to a weapon, it gets back some health (or does it reset the weapon to new? I don't know)

So what is the best strategy when you pick up a blank weapon? Fuse something to it asap to boost its power? or use it a little while and then fuse something to get more uses out of it?

Comment: You can freely unfuse a weapon and fuse something else to it at any point, so there doesn't seem any benefit in waiting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does fusing weapons affect durability?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/402802/how-does-fusing-weapons-affect-durability) The top answer there discusses the intricacies of fusing a new weapon vs. a weapon about to break.

Comment: Kind of, yes and no. But I think the discussion is already well started there and this is a dupe of the sub discussion.

Comment: The short answer is: "Always fuse a weapon. There is no benefit from un-fusing and then re-fusing the same weapon, since it won't increase the durability further".

Comment: Based on the tip in the loading screen, fusing **adds** durability. If that is a mathematical addition, there's no benefit from delaying the fuse but there is a drawback (not yet having the additional attack power)